# Question about yuri and yaoi

Tags: discussion

Why is this

[What is the equivalent of "seme" and "uke" in yuri culture?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28319/what-is-the-equivalent-of-seme-and-uke-in-yuri-culture)

really on-topic here and not that this should be migrated to japanese stackexchange? Just because of the genres yaoi and yuri? Not saying it should be migrated. Just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Topics about the subculture of anime and manga are on-topic. In this case the terms, along with "Riba" are generally on-topic, with some exceptions (such as requests, and recommendations, content that may be overly explicit).

While they are terms prevalent in the gay community in Japan, it is a generally accepted fact among the (anime and manga) subculture that the terms originate from BL genre industry and especially the male/male doujinshi community in Japan.